# How can I load https certs in axios if its client side and cant read files?

Tags: reactjs, ssl, axios

I have this axios object

```
    import axios from 'axios';
import constants from '../constants.js';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import fs from 'fs';
import https from 'https';


    const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
      cert: fs.readFileSync('../landing-page-server/certs/cert.pem'),
      key: fs.readFileSync('../landing-page-server/certs/key.pem'),
      passphrase: 'random'
    })

    const API = axios.create({
      baseURL: `${constants.urlBackend}`,
      timeout: 10000,
      // headers: {
      //   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // },
    }, { httpsAgent });

    API.interceptors.request.use(
      config => {
        var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');

        if (accesstoken) {
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accesstoken}`;
        } else {
          delete API.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
        }
        return config;
      },

      error => Promise.reject(error)
    );

    export default API;
```

Problem is that, fs wont work because its in react, so how am I supposed to read that data and create a valid axios object which will be able to communicate with my ssl backend ?

Comment: Is this piece of code only running on server side?

Comment: No, this is client side, in react @Gihan . I use it as API.post(.....) and so on, to make requests to my server

Comment: Then I'm afraid you can't load custom certificates on the client-side. Maybe you should proxy API requests which you'll have to use custom certificates.